# Why is future price equal to $E^Q[S_T]$?

Tags: option-pricing

I understand that forward price is $k=E^{Q_T}[S_T]$. 
Why is future price equal to $E^Q[S_T]$ under the risk neutral measure?

Comment: See Theorem 3.7 of the book [Methods of Mathematical Finance](https://www.amazon.com/Methods-Mathematical-Probability-Stochastic-Modelling/dp/1493968149).

Comment: Also Section 5.6.2 of the book [_Stochastic Calculus For Finance II_](https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-II-Continuous-Time/dp/144192311X).